# DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /xxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-location-11.2.2.aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to compile my project I get this weird error:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForProdDevelopmentDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-location-11.2.2.aar/f5b9886774f73d8b64cfd9701f91e8cc/jars/classes.jar

**What I tried:**

1. Added `multiDexEnabled true` to app gradle.
2. Added `android.enableD8.desugaring = true` and `android.enableD8=true` to gradle.properties
3. Also removed .gradle folder and did rebuild + clean
4. Also did the following: SDK manager -> Google play services -> updated. Rebuild + clean afterwards.

---

AS version: 3.1.4

App gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion Android.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion Android.buildToolsVersion
    flavorDimensions "...", "type"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        versionName 'xxx'
        versionCode xxx
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion Android.targetSdkVersion //Android.targetSdkVersion holds value "27"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
        preDexLibraries = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {           
        test {
            dimension "xxx"
            applicationIdSuffix '.xxx'
            versionNameSuffix 'x'
            manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                    onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
        }
        production {
            dimension "xxx"
            manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                    onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
        }
        development {
            dimension "type"
            resConfigs "xxhdpi"
        }
        normal {
            dimension "type"
        }
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "..."
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'build-data.properties'
        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
        implementation project(':projectxxx')
        implementation project(':tifCompanion')
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
        kapt           "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
        implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
        implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5"
        kapt           "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
        api            "com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.1"
        implementation "com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.1"
        api            "com.android.support:recommendation:27.1.1"
        implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"
        implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
}
```

*projectxxx* which was implemented has these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api project(':JsonAPI') //https://github.com/faogustavo/JSONApi
    api            "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.61"
    implementation "com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5"
    api            "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    api            "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.0"
    api            "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1"
}
```

Comment: Which version of `play-services-location` you have used.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed 15.0.0

Comment: Are you tried this: Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.

Comment: Yes. Result is the same.

Comment: Would you please try adding this `android.enableD8=true` on gradle.properties

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Did that too, haha. Updated original post with what I have already done.

Comment: Post all your dependencies

Comment: @parekhkruti26 Re-check post, please. Weirdly, the error mentions play-services-location library, but it is not used in this gradle file at all (it's used in other app gradle and that project compiles good).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using all play-services with versions `15.x.x`, and error is mentioning `11.2.2`, this means that some other library is bringing in this dependency.

This type of error can be solved by following steps:

1. run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` command in terminal. (This will generate dependency hierarchy)
2. Check for the dependency bringing in `play-services-location` dependency and `exclude` it from that dependency like below:

   ```
   compile ('<dependency-bringing-play-services-location>') {
     exclude  group:'com.google.android.gms'
   }
   ```
3. Add play-services location dependency explicitly.